# How can I remove the resource type segment from my URI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, resources, routes

My project has files and folders, represented by `File` and `Folder` models. The project is functionally complete, and now I'm looking to cleanup the URI scheme while keeping my named routes.

My route contains a simple nested resource:

```
resources :folders do
  resources :files
end
```

Currently, `folder_file_path(@folder, @file)` outputs:

```
/folders/12/files/3
```

I've overridden `to_param` to output a human-readable slug, yielding

```
/folders/my-folder/files/my-file
```

I'd like to go a step further and remove the redundant `folders` and `files` segments from the URI. How can I modify my nested `resources` so that `folder_file_path` will output the following?

```
/my-folder/my-file
```

I'd like to keep my routes simple, using nested `resources` instead of moving to a longer mess of custom named routes, which is how I've currently achieved this:

```
get ':folder_slug' => 'folders#show', :as => 'folder'
get ':folder_slug/edit => 'folders#edit', :as => 'edit_folder'
# ...
delete ':folder_slug' => 'folders#destroy', : as => 'folder'

get ':folder_slug/:file_slug' => 'files#show', :as => 'folder_file'
get ':folder_slug/:file_slug/edit' => 'files#edit', :as => 'edit_folder_file'
# ...
delete ':folder_slug/:file_slug' => 'files#delete', :as => 'folder_file'
```

Comment: You might be able to leverage URL rewrites, but I'd just stick to what you have now.  The way you created your routes is the approach I would have taken.

Comment: An unnecessary upvote to make you hit 20k rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
resources :folders, path: ''
resources :folders, path: '', only: [] do
  resources :files, path: ''    
end
```

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but it could be useful for someone else

Comment: Fantastic, tested it and it works well in Rails 3.1 with Ruby 1.9. It's never too late for a correct answer.